# Как правильно собирать проект с Hibernate Maven-м (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException)?

Tags: maven

Собственно, в результате нужно получить jar. При этом часть зависимостей тянется с Maven, часть же - локальные.

pom.xml - следующий

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.alex4321.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alex4321.mylib</groupId>
            <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/mylib.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.alex4321.botweb.Application</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>lib/</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`mav package` выдает

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.967 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-29T09:29:16+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/283M  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

При старте же

```
# java -jar target/builded.jar ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
    at com.alex4321.botweb.Database.initialize(Database.java:11)
    at com.alex4321.botweb.Application.main(Application.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Однако `ls target/dom4j*jar` выдает `target/dom4j-1.6.1.jar`

Ну и да - разумеется, при старте из IDE проблемы нет

Comment: classpath-то при запуске прописываете?

Comment: Из переменной окуржения CLASSPATH ведь должно подтянуться, если верно понял? Если так - то, если я верно понимаю работу с ней - безразлично : http://pastebin.com/DkdqKZgK

Comment: `$ java -classpath dom4j-1.6.1.jar:. -jar builder.jar ../test/config.json`
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException`